# How to remove the formatting of some column headers in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slickgrid

I currently have a table in SlickGrid, with headers like below:

[image: Picture of headers of SlickGrid table.]

I have several columns whose headers I want to retain (they are black with white text), and some columns whose headers I want to remove, leaving them blank (these columns are indicated with the arrows). At the moment I have overwritten the existing CSS for the headers I want to leave  blank, but I am left with the two lines above and below the cells, that you can see in the image.

I was wondering if anyone had a method for removing these lines?

Things I have tried:

- Overwriting all of the border properties for the cells in the CSS.
- Removing the border formatting in the default CSS for SlickGrid.

The code for overwriting the existing CSS is:

```
/* Used to apply CSS to the headers of the SlickGrid */
.slickGridBlankHeader
{
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
    border-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

This class is applied using:

```
var headerColumns = $('.slick-header-columns').children();

    for (i = 0; i < headerColumns.length; ++i) {
        if ($.inArray(i, CHECKBOX_EDIT_COL_POSITIONS) == -1) {
            $(headerColumns[i]).addClass('slickGridHeader');
        } else {
            $(headerColumns[i]).addClass('slickGridBlankHeader');
        }
    }
```

Comment: share you code piece mate

Comment: did you test your css? Does it work when you manually add the class to the html?

Comment: Please setup a JSFiddle, it would be much easier to help with seeing complete, reproducable code.

Comment: @Gavriel the CSS works, as it makes the background white (which is not the default). I don't think it's a case of changing the CSS for the headers, as that does not control those two lines. It may be a case of changing CSS in another place, or adding more to the headers to cover the lines.

Comment: I don't understand: as I see it there might be 2 separate problems: 1. css. This one you should be able to fix manually by editing the html (add class="slickGridBlankHeader" or class="slickGridBlankHeader") and the css. When it works with both classes exactly as you want, then 2. javascript: it probably doesn't do what you think it does. You can add debugging console.log( i + " in if"), console.log(i + " in else") for example